# SQL Query Search Where Not The Same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with columns ID and Product..
And have data with my customer buyed product id array('1','2')

I want to suggest to my customer where product that my costumer didn't buy.

So how can i write the query? i wrote the following

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE ID IS NOT IN(1,2);
```

Comment: What's your dbms?Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I'm using mysqli

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm using PHPMyadmin.. And using codeigniter framework for my website..

Comment: @JafranJS what is the expected result and what is the actual result ?

Comment: Your DBMS is MySQL, then.

Comment: I'm using query that posted, actual result is showing what i searched id ( 1 and 2) but my expected result is i want show all record except searched id (1 and 2)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Please show sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove `is` from your query

```
 SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE ID NOT IN(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the select statement you provided should work. But as you are working with a MySql database I assume that the customer purchase information can already be found in your database. Maybe in a table like this:

```
purchasetbl
usrid   prodid    purchasedate
-----   ------    ------------
23      1         2018-07-20
23      2         2018-07-21
24      1         2018-05-14
```

You can then do your select statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1 FROM purchasetbl WHERE prodid=id AND usrid=23)
```

(The above example is assuming that you are serving customer `23`.)